# Function that returns a Generic List

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, dynamic

I have WPF application project and I'm using EF.
I want something like this.

```
NorthwindEntities nwModel = new NorthwindEntities();
Employees emp;
List mylist = GenericFunc("emp.FirstName"); => returns a List<string>
and
List mylist = GenericFunc("emp.PostalCode"); => returns a List<int>

public static List<T> GenericFunc<T>(string myfield)
{...}
```

Sorry if I made any mistakes.

Comment: What code do you have so far? What's the question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a string paramter to represent a filed so :

```
public static List<T> GenericFunc<T>(string myfield, string TABLENAME)
{
   return nwModel.ExecuteQuery<T>("SELECT " + myfield + " FROM " + TABLENAME).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You got me:p, I want to make a dynamic query(select) ; I've added System.Data.Linq and I still can't use after nwModel.ExecuteQuery<T> ?!

Comment: Here is my original post in WPF forum : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0d827ce8-0511-4f8f-9da2-42d478d023fc

Comment: My code works LINQ(Dbml context), for EF try : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738694.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You'd be better off using LINQ instead of your "GenericFunc"  Like so:

```
List<string> nameList = (from e in emp select emp.FirstName).ToList();
//and
List<int> postCodeList = (from e in emp select emp.PostalCode).ToList();
```